# What strategy should be used to minimise page initialisation jitter?

Tags: jquery, html

When using frameworks such as jQuery/UI such as the button widget the page will jitter about as the layout is being processed on page load. I'm wondering what is the best strategy to minimise this?

I've set the `body` tag to `display: none` and then `$(function() { ${'body').show(); })` which works though I have to wonder if there is a better way.

Comment: Not sure, but this does seem like a method used alot. I notice a lot of sites wont display data until its element has been fully loaded.

Comment: If you give the elements the classes/structure that jQuery ui will be giving them when you initialize them, the jitter will be less noticeable, maybe even gone.

Answer (score 2):

The most seamless solution would be to give the elements the classes/structure that jquery ui will give it after initialization.

Using a jQuery UI button as an example, here is before:

```
<input type="submit" value="A submit button" />
```

and here is after:

```
<input type="submit" value="A submit button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
```

If you used the after rather than before in your actual html, the jitter (otherwise known as a FOUC) would no longer happen on that button when you initialized it with jQuery UI because it already has the classes.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, that's a good solution for simple buttons, but what about more complex elements like tables (I use jqGrid) and the jQuery/UI tab control?

Comment: Do you think there is anything inherently dangerous about using the hide/show of `body` like I am at the moment? In this situation though you get a FOWC :)

Comment: well, hide/show of body doesn't really stop the FOUC, it just makes it more uniform. You can use this same technique on all jQuery UI stuff (including tabs), however with the grid, you can make it better by hiding the grid itself until it is ready, or having it initially show in a "Loading..." state.